# Prove that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: pi

I haven't found a way, except using advanced methods, to prove the irrationality of $\pi$.

It is possible to prove that $\pi$ is irrational, using only elementary algebra?

Comment: There isn't a truly easy proof (that i am aware of), but Hermite's argument isn't too bad.  You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)

Comment: An algebraic definition of $\pi$ (as opposed to a geometric definition like "the ratio of any circle's circumference to its diameter) is a bit involved and so any proof of its irrationality would likely also be involved.

Comment: I would typically expect a proof to use the fact that $\pi$ is a positive root (in fact, the least positive root) of $\sin,$ but then defining $\sin$ in a satisfactory way is already involved (and then there's the additional point of proving that there actually exists a least positive root of $\sin$). Typically, satisfactory definitions already involved a fair amount of analysis, so that elementary algebra is already insufficient. The fact is that, since $\pi$ is (in fact) transcendental, it isn't an altogether algebraic object. Some analysis would seem to be needed.

Comment: Elementary algebra only?  No.  There isn't.

Comment: I think neither https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364970/help-with-proving-that-pi-is-irrational nor https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076966/simple-proof-that-pi-is-irrational-using-prime-factors-of-denominator have an answer that answers this question. Maybe the task was to give a short simple proof that doesn't rely on a previously proven result that's difficult to prove without proving it.